# Refreshing a jwt token in cookie using websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, passport.js

I'm a bit confused with the general flow of refreshing access/jwt tokens. I'm using socketcluster as the main way of communication between the client an the server.

The initial request (serve the html) is done by express. Client can login via github using the passport.js github strategy

```
passport.use(new githubStrategy({
  clientID:'********',
  clientSecret:'*******',
  callbackURL:'http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback'
  },
  function(accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done){
    profile.token = jwt.sign({
      id:profile.id,
      username:profile.username
    },'rush2112')
    return done(null,profile)
  }
))
```

Social strategies with passport seem to use sessions which i'm ignoring and generating a jwt token for client login.

on successfull login, i store the jwt in a browser cookie using the below

```
  app.get('/auth/github',passport.authenticate('github'))

  app.get('/auth/github/callback',passport.authenticate('github',{failureRedirect:'/fail'}),
    function(req,res){
      var text = JSON.stringify({id_token: req.user.token})
      res.cookie('id_token',text,{ expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true })
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  )
```

I can then access the cookie from the socket using `socket.request.headers.cookie`

i then proceed to decode it using

```
  var cookie = decodeURIComponent(socket.request.headers.cookie)

  var id_token = JSON.parse(cookie.split('=')[1])
  var decoded = jwt.verify(id_token.id_token,'rush2112')
```

I have a couple of questions :

1. Is the above approach valid or am i ignoring anything?
2. How do i refresh tokens? Do i refresh the cookie itself or just the id_token present in the cookie.
3. Is there anyway i can reset/set the cookie outside of express? Possibly through websockets itself?

Comment: What sockets library are you using? As a note if you like, you can change a cookie value from client side. https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: I'm using socketcluster .. i've set the cookies to http-only .. would js-cookie still work?

Comment: I think it should work, but I didn't tried. Also take a look at this: https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio but you're going to need to use sessions.